# How to take back storage from my postgres db

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a table named duplicates_duplicatebackendentry_documents that has a size of 49gb. This table has 2 indexes that are each 25 gb. And two constraints that are also each 25gb.

The table is used by the duplicates module in a django app I deployed. I have now turned off the module. I am unable to run full vacuuum because I do not have the space necessary to run it. Deleting the table returns the storage (I tested in a dev env) but is there a way I can delete the bloat but keep the table, its constraints and indexes? I just want to empty the bloat along with all the contents.

[image: Bloated table]

[image: table and object sizes]

Comment: What makes you think there is bloat?

Comment: because all the other tables are really small and most of the table size is because of the two indexes.

Comment: Neither of those things indicate that this table is bloated.  There are queries and extensions you can use to measure bloat directly.

Comment: i see, I will check them out. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to empty the bloat along with all the contents.

The canonical way to do that is

```
TRUNCATE duplicates_duplicatebackendentry_documents;
```

which will render the table and all its indexes empty.